# WPF, MVVM, доступ к свойствам элемента пользовательского контрола, тиражированного в вкладках UI?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Не могу решить такую проблему. Есть пользовательский контрол с несколькими TextBox. Создан также шаблон, содержащий 6 таких контролов. С помощью шаблона заполняются вкладки основного окна приложения. Шаблон связан с моделью представления. Не могу найти способ, как добраться до свойства IsEnabled каждого конкретного текстбокса из основного окна? Более подробно с примерами кода по ссылке на англоязычной версии стэка: [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107182/how-to-access-wpf-user-controls-elements-inside-viewmodel-which-is-a-content-of). Может у кого-нибудь есть какие-нибудь идеи?

Comment: Добавьте прямо в этот вопрос примеры вашего кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну можно через `ViewModel` делать:

```
public class Module: INotifyPropertyChanged
{

private double _ch1;
public double Ch1
{
    get { return this._ch1; }
    set
    {
        if (_ch1 == value) return;
        _ch1 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Ch1");
    }
}


private bool _isEnbl;
public bool  IsEnbl
{
    get { return this._isEnbl; }
    set
    {
        if (_isEnbl== value) return;
        _isEnbl= value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsEnbl");
    }
}
```

И попросту делаешь привязку тут:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication4.MyModuleFrame"
     <!-- ... -->
     x:Name="mUserControl">
  <Grid>
     <!-- ... -->
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ItemSource.Ch1, ElementName=mUserControl}" IsEnabled="{Binding ItemSource.IsEnbl, ElementName=mUserControl}"  Name="txtCh1"/>
    <!-- other textboxes -->
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Гениально просто! Спасибо огромное, Сергей, теперь работает! @Сергей

Answer (score 1):

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string property = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
```

Как небольшой лайфхак, чтобы не указывать имя свойства [CallerMemberName] сделает это за вас, соответсвтенно:

```
public double Ch1
 {
 get { return this._ch1; }
 set
   {
    if (_ch1 == value) 
           return;
    _ch1 = value;
    NotifyPropertyChanged();
   }
```

}

Может поможет :)

Comment: Спасибо! Пригодится! @Morgomirius